# How do I translate HTML entities in a string?

Tags: html, objective-c

I have a JSON array of team names downloaded from a server and one of the teams has `&amp;` in the name. What's the best way to translate HTML elements like this to the proper string?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                        NULL,
                                        (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}

NSString* decodeFromPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (__bridge NSString *)
    CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NULL,
                                                        (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                                        CFSTR(""),
                                                        kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

URLencode decoding work for you.

Comment: "Percent escapes" (e.g. `%20`) and "HTML entities" (e.g. `&lt;`) are completely different things.